# how can i insert an empty subtitle

Tags: ffmpeg

i have a bunch of mp4 files and i would like to convert them to mkv, so that the automatic selection auf audio and subtitle track of vlc works.
the thing is some of them have 4 subtitles  (first german and english only for foreign languages and then german and english for all) and some of them only 2 (because in those episodes there are no foreign languages). Can i insert 2 empty subtitle tracks before them so that i can set my vlc to select the first or second subtitle when i watch them?

i convert the episodes with 4 subtitles like this:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -map 0:4 -map 0:5 -map 0:6 out.mkv`

0:0 is of course the video

0:1 and 0:2 are audio tracks

the rest are the subtitles

BTW: is there a language code for forced subtitles? `-metadata:s:s:1 language=?`

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Why not tell ffmpeg which subtitle to set as default?

Comment: because depending on the people watching with me, i sometimes want to have the first or the second track. But if it is too complicated i could change the order of those with 4 subtitles so that position 0 are always the complete subtitles and 2,3 either nothing or the ones for foreign langs

Comment: Answered your main question. I don't understand what you are asking with your second question "is there a language code for forced subtitles?".

Answer (score 1):

Make "empty" subtitles. If it is completely empty you will get the `Invalid data found when processing input` error, so add timing with no actual subtitles.

Example `empty.srt`:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:05,000
```

Now mux:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i empty.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```